# Is Opensearch 2.11.1 rest high level client compatible with elasticsearch 8.10.4?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

For our project we are using elasticsearch as indexing backend and using opensearch rest high level client to talk to it. Currently we are on Elasticsearch version 7.17 and opensearch rest high level client version is 1.3.

We have to move to Elasticsearch 8.10 and there are some request/response format change between the two. So we are thinking of moving to opensearch client 2.x version but not sure if that is compatible or not. I couldn't find any document claiming that they are compatible.

Comment: Why don't you use Elasticsearch client?

Answer (score 0):

It might work but I'd not recommend this as depending on your usage, it might break by reading the response and some new APIs are not available.

And more than this, you should definitely move to the nez Elasticsearch Java client. The high level client is not maintained anymore.